# Trigger On PermissionSetAssignment Object and Alternatives

Tags: apex, trigger

I have one requirement where on deletion of permission set , i have to perform certain logic. But as i have understood from various articles that, Triggers, process builders or Visual Flows are NOT supported on `PermissionSetAssignment` object .

Just wanted check with the forum if anyone has come across the same and got any alternatives to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

Currently it is not possible to have a trigger on this entity, you can vote on https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrBwAAK

There are 2 workarounds:

1) Create a batch that checks the records and does what you need

2) Create a custom component/page and use apex to add/remove permissions sets